# Google apps not working on chrome browser (V.76.0.3809.132 (Official Build) (64-bit))

Tags: google-chrome

When I am trying to open any chrome apps like gmail, gdrive, youtube or google.com it is throwing

> ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

I did reinstalled the latest version, and before installing it, removed all related details to chrome, restarted the system and then reinstalled it.
The websites like naukri.com, stackoverflow.com or any other apart from chrome apps are working fine.

Comment: You're in the wrong place. SO is for programming questions. You should try https://superuser.com instead.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/4420967/james-z : Thanks, I will.